# Delete files with illegal symbols

Tags: c#, file, delete-file

I need to remove some files from a directory, but I get the following exception

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Illegales Zeichen im Pfad.

Code is pretty simple:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string path = @"F:\A";

    var files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
    foreach(var file in files)
    {
        File.Delete(file);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Here is a screenshot with the files.

[image: Screenshot]

I cannot delete/rename the files...

**OS**: windows 7

Comment: can you delete/rename/copy them in your explorer window?

Comment: @Waescher no, that's why I try with a program. Python, C, Java were also tested and no way... Through command line it also doesn't work.

Comment: if you just want to get rid of these files, did you try to remove the parental directory with something like "rd /s /q F:\A"?

Comment: @Waescher I tried. The main folder can be renamed without problem, but not deleted.

Comment: I'm sorry but if you can't delete those files in the windows explorer or dosbox, I'm pretty sure you won't be able to do it in C# or any other programming language.

Comment: I had something similar (a file without a name - just an empty string) an could not delete it in windows. In my case I could delete it by booting a linux CD

Comment: How did you get those file names in the first place? My guess is that the file system is corrupted and you should first perform a chkdsk to fix all issues.

Comment: hopefully its just a file system problem and NOT a virus

Comment: A bit going into a similar direction (renaming instead of deleting): http://superuser.com/questions/31587/how-to-force-windows-to-rename-a-file-with-a-special-character

Comment: I just formatted the unit. The file system was indeed corrupted, but a chkdsk didn't help. I opened the question because of curiosity and I would like to keep it, in case someone knows a programmatic solution.